# CircleCI : $ npm test failing

Tags: node.js, testing, continuous-integration, jasmine-node, circleci

I'm trying to use [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) for one of my node.js application. I'm trying to learn the way circleci works.

My app and test cases are running fine locally. I'm using `jasmine-node` for test.

But when I'm trying to build my app on circleci I'm getting below error. Below is a screenshot from circleci:
[image]

Please let me know anyone has any idea on this!

Comment: its hard to help with this piece of information. This question does not have enough information for error to be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleCi is saying that `jasmine-node` isn't installed.

Add the following code to your circle.yml file.

```
dependencies:
  post:
    - sudo npm install jasmine-node -g
```